# QtWebEngine - synchronously execute JavaScript to read function result

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, callback, qtwebengine

I have the following method in one of my C++ classes (using QtWebEngine):

```
    QString get()
    {
        QString result;

        view->page()->runJavaScript("test();", [this](const QVariant &v)
            {
                result = v.toString();
            });

        return result;
    }
```

It is to execute `test()` JS function and return the result of this invocation.

Unfortunately, the callback is asynchronous and the program crashes. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The callback is asynchronous because the JavaScript execution occurs not only in another thread but in another *process*. So there is no way to make it fully synchronous.

The best possible solution would be to migrate your C++ code to work asynchronously. If you can't do that, the only feasible solution is to use `QEventLoop`, somewhat like this:

```
void ranJavaScript()
{
    emit notifyRanJavaScript();
}

QString get()
{
    QString result;
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(notifyRanJavaScript()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    view->page()->runJavaScript("test();", [this](const QVariant &v)
        {
            result = v.toString();
            this.ranJavaScript();
        });

    loop.exec();
    return result;
}
```

However, note that this example is oversimplified for a real-world usage: you need to ensure the JavaScript was not ran before the event loop is started. The most proper way to do that would involve implementing a proper slot instead of a lambda + factoring out the call to `view->page()->runJavaScript()` into another slot which would be called asynchronously *after* starting the event loop. It is a lot of glue code for such a seemingly simple task but that's what it takes. Here's an example:

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef TMP_MAIN_WINDOW_H
#define TMP_MAIN_WINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVariant>

class QWebEngineView;
class QPushButton;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0);

    QString get();

    void onScriptEnded(const QVariant & data);

Q_SIGNALS:
    void notifyRanJavaScript();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void onButtonPressed();

    void startScript();

private:
    QWebEngineView *    m_view;
    QPushButton *       m_button;
    QString             m_scriptResult;
};

#endif // TMP_MAIN_WINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_view = new QWebEngineView;
    QWebEnginePage * page = new QWebEnginePage(m_view);
    m_view->setPage(page);

    QString html = QStringLiteral("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\""
                                  "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"><html>"
                                  "<head><h3>head</h3>\n</head>"
                                  "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function test() { return \"A!\"; }</script>"
                                  "<body>text\n</body></html>");
    m_view->page()->setHtml(html);

    m_button = new QPushButton;
    m_button->setMinimumWidth(35);
    m_button->setText(QStringLiteral("Test"));
    QObject::connect(m_button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(onButtonPressed()));

    QHBoxLayout * buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    buttonLayout->addWidget(m_button);
    buttonLayout->addStretch();

    QVBoxLayout * viewLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    viewLayout->addLayout(buttonLayout);
    viewLayout->addWidget(m_view);

    QWidget * widget = new QWidget(this);
    widget->setLayout(viewLayout);

    setCentralWidget(widget);
}

QString MainWindow::get()
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(notifyRanJavaScript()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

    // Schedule the slot to run in 0 seconds but not right now
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(startScript()));

    // The event loop would block until onScriptEnded slot is executed
    loop.exec();

    // If we got here, the script has been executed and the result was saved in m_scriptResult
    return m_scriptResult;
}

void MainWindow::onScriptEnded(const QVariant & data)
{
    qDebug() << QStringLiteral("Script ended: ") << data;
    m_scriptResult = data.toString();
    emit notifyRanJavaScript();
}

void MainWindow::onButtonPressed()
{
    QString str = get();
    QMessageBox::information(this, QStringLiteral("Script result"), str,
                             QMessageBox::StandardButton::Ok);
}

struct Functor
{
    Functor(MainWindow & window) : m_window(window) {}
    void operator()(const QVariant & data)
    {
        m_window.onScriptEnded(data);
    }
    MainWindow & m_window;
};

void MainWindow::startScript()
{
    qDebug() << QStringLiteral("Start script");
    m_view->page()->runJavaScript(QStringLiteral("test();"), Functor(*this));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, but doesn't seem to work.
It's getting stack in loop.exec(); - this doesn't finish. I changed view to be a pointer (and not reference) but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Replaced the example with the one which I have tested.

Comment: It works perfectly fine! Thank you very much. I have also done this using std mutex and cond. var and blocking queue. But I had to spawn new thread because, in fact, thread calling runJavaScript and thread executing callback are the same threads... I checked this using std::this_thread::id - and those are not different processes (as you've written) but exactly the same thread.
Anyway your solution is truly synchronous so exactly what I needed. Cheers!

Comment: I did not say the callback is executed in a different process. I said that **JavaScript** code (that being the argument of `runJavaScript`) is executed (really JIT-compiled and executed) in a different process called `QWebEngineProcess`.

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry's solution only works partially, unfortunately. In his example the code is invoked upon pressing a button. However, if the same code is moved to execute while the window is loading, the slot for the finished script (onScriptEnded) is never called. To fix this, I had to wrap the call to the evaluation of JS itself (called evaluateJavaScript in my project) in another QTimer::singleShot:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, [&] { evaluateJavaScript(); });
```

Unfortunately, in my real project I have many calls, often one evaluation waiting for another before it to finish. It's practically impossible to use this every single time so I still look for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the [kchmviewer](https://github.com/gyunaev/kchmviewer/) project, I found a very easy way to wait for the result of the runJavaScript function. The [following code](https://github.com/gyunaev/kchmviewer/blob/3876af816c58c6402612c5ecd4b5d18e0e1d9751/src/viewwindow_webengine.cpp#L198) is part of the [ViewWindow class](https://github.com/gyunaev/kchmviewer/blob/3876af816c58c6402612c5ecd4b5d18e0e1d9751/src/viewwindow_webengine.h) which inherits from QWebEngineView.

```
int ViewWindow::getScrollbarPosition()
{
    QAtomicInt value = -1;

    page()->runJavaScript("document.body.scrollTop", [&value](const QVariant &v)
        {
            qDebug( "value retrieved: %d\n", v.toInt());
            value = v.toInt();
        });

    while (value == -1)
    {
        QApplication::processEvents();
    }

    qDebug( "scroll value %d", value.load() );
    return value;
}
```