# How to block thread until a function returns in another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, thread-safety

If I have a main thread and a separate, permanent worker QThread:

```
// Main thread where the event loop and QCoreApplication runs.
class NetworkController : public QObject {
public:
Q_OBJECT

    void connect_to_ap()
    {
        WifiAP *myAP = netMgr.get_best_ap();

        myAP->connect("my_psk_password");
    }

    // This is a class from a 3rd-party library, which contains, owns
    //  and manages the lifetime of "WifiAP" instances.
    NetworkManager netMgr;
};

// Separate thread where a state machine runs.
class StateMachineWorker : public QObject {
public:
Q_OBJECT

    void on_ready_to_connect_event()
    {
        // HERE: How to trigger NetworkController::connect_to_ap() and 
        // *block* until it returns.
    }

    NetworkController *pNetCtrlr;
}
```

When the state machine class enters a certain state it should connect to an AP (Access Point). The `NetworkController` has the functionality to connect to an AP.

I am trying to figure out a way that the state machine can do this in a thread-safe way. The problem is `NetworkManager` is always updating its list of `WifiAP` instances: they are created and destroyed often.
It would not be thread-safe for `StateMachineWorker` to call `pNetCtrlr->connect_to_ap()` directly (as the `NetworkManager` in the `NetworkController` thread could at the same time delete the `WifiAP` instance).

So what I would like is in `StateMachineWorker::on_ready_to_connect_event()` to somehow signal the `NetworkController` to run its `connect_to_ap()` method **in `NetworkController`'s own thread**, and to block the `StateMachineWorker` thread until `connect_to_ap()` has finished doing its stuff. The reason I want the state machine to be blocked is if I did not block and let it enter the event loop, it could receive some event that would make it transition to another state **before** `connect_to_ap()` has finished executing; this must not happen.

Mutex locks to protect the list of `WifiAP` in `NetworkManager` would not work as they would need to be inserted inside the 3rd-party library.

Comment: Using a mutex?? ^^

Comment: cond_var or mutex should do the work

Comment: @Robert See my last sentence in the question. The mutex would need to be inside the 3rd-party lib, which I do not want to edit. There is no point mutex locking `netMgr`, because the `WifiAP` instances are deleted automatically inside `NetworkManager` (via signals/slots and what-not).

Comment: Using wait() on StateMachineWorker thread ?

Comment: @SamuraiJack But I do not see how the `StateMachineWorker` can indicate to `NetworkController` thread that it should run `connect_to_ap()` in `NetworkController`'s thread, not the state machine's.

Comment: `StateMachineWorker` can send the signal to `NetworkController` notifying that it should run `connect_to_ap` and then block itself using [QEventLoop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html). You could connect the signal from `NetworkController` notifying about its job's end to the event loop's `quit` slot which would unblock `StateMachineWorker` and let it work further. For some details on `QEventLoop` usage see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331583/1217285) answer of mine.

Comment: QWaitCondition allows a thread to tell other threads that some sort of condition has been met. One or many threads can block waiting for a QWaitCondition to set a condition with wakeOne() or wakeAll(). Use wakeOne() to wake one randomly selected thread or wakeAll() to wake them all.

Comment: @rak007 Could you give an idea of how to do this in my case?  @Dmitry thanks for the `QEventLoop` idea; it's a risky solution, from what I've read. I'll keep it in mind

Comment: @DBedrenko This ? void on_ready_to_connect_event()
    {
      // Change your connect_to_ap return type to bool if you can
      std::packaged_task<bool()> task(std::bind(this->pNetCtrlr->connect_to_ap));
      std::future<bool> results = task.get_future();
      task();
      task.wait();
      std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Everything went OK ? " << task.get() << std::endl;
    }

Comment: @rak007 Thanks for your help, but wouldn't this run the `task` in a new thread that is concurrent to the `NetworkController` thread? That would mean the data race still exists.

Comment: Well this is probably somthing that could happen

Comment: @rak007 Yes, this is why I'm trying to execute `connect_to_ap()` in the `NetworkController` thread where we can work with `netMgr` and its `WifiAP` instances without threat of them being deleted or modified from another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) with parameter [`Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). This connection type adds all the blocking logic for you and you don't have to change the third party library at all.

A general example:

**objects.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <iostream>

class Object : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

public slots:
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "Hello";
    thread()->msleep(2000);
    std::cout << " world!" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Caller : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  void call(Object* o) {
    std::cout << "Calling..." << std::endl;
    metaObject()->invokeMethod(o, "foo", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
    std::cout << "Finished!" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "objects.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  QThread t;
  Object o;
  o.moveToThread(&t);

  t.start();

  Caller().call(&o);

  return a.exec();
}
```

The counterpart is that the method to be called must be a slot. If `connect_to_ap` is not already a slot you can create a bridge object that do the job, as explained below.

Have in mind that this *bridge* object must live in the same thread as the `NetworkController` (in your case the main thread), so the slot is queued in the correct events loop. You can take a look at [`QObject::moveToThread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) for further information.

A quick draft would be something like:

```
class NetworkControllerBridge : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

  NetworkController* nc;

public:
  NetworkControllerBridge(NetworkController* nc_) : nc(nc_) {}

public slots:
  void connect_to_ap() {
    nc->connect_to_ap();
  }
};

// ...

void on_ready_to_connect_event()
{
  NetworkControllerBridge bridge(pNetCtrlr);
  bridge.moveToThread(qApp->thread());
  metaObject()->invokeMethod(&bridge, "connect_to_ap", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
}
```

**Update**

Another way to call a method through `invokeMethod` is to mark it as [`Q_INVOKABLE`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE). Although you still need the *bridge* since you cannot modify the library, I mention this for completeness of the answer.

Comment: Thank you, sir! The perfect solution.